# QIWI API in Discord bot

Tags: discord.py

Good day! I want to implement payment acceptance using QIWI in discord, but I don't quite understand how I can link the QIWI API library and the Discord.py library. Programming language: Python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to include what all you have and what all you have tried in your question, so that we can review what you have, improve it, give suggestions on it in order to fix it :)

---

Here are some useful resources on QIWI

- [QIWI Official API Docs](https://developer.qiwi.com/index-en.html)
- [pyqiwi package documentation](https://pyqiwi.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/)
- [pyqiwi Quick Start](https://pyqiwi.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/readme.html#id4)

---

And here are some useful resources on `discord.py`

- [discord.py official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [discord.py Quick Start](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)
- [discord.py bot examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples)

---

A basic bot application can be created as such using `discord.py`

```py
from discord.ext import commands

# Bot instance
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

# a simple ping command that will reply with "pong" when you use.
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

# bot token can be accessed from discord developer portal
client.run("token")
```